# Is peer review process by the US Department of Energy, Office of Science anonymous?

Tags: peer-review

The title says it all, could not find anywhere this information clearly written. Would appreciate a short feedback.

Comment: Do you have a link to the funding/grants you're applying for? Your question could be better framed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't submitted grants to those departments, but for most federal grants, the researchers applying are not blinded. The reviewers for other departments are also often not blinded, but you have to dig to find who they are- for instance, for the NIH you find the study section that will review and find the list of who is in that review group.

Comment: For NIH, you can find out who was in your study section, but you can't find out who were the actual readers.  I suppose they're ALL reviewers, as each assigns a score, but usually three section members read the grant and recommend the scores.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Even with the study section list, you do not know who exactly reviewed the grant. Thanks for the clarification!